# Not able to get IIS details using ServerManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Asp.net 2.0 application. This application hosted in IIS for .Net framework 2.0. I have created a custom page to get IIS details. I am using below code to get IIS details :

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
string DefaultSiteName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
Model.SiteName = DefaultSiteName;
Site defaultSite = manager.Sites[DefaultSiteName];
string appVirtaulPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
var app = defaultSite.Applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path.ToLower() == appVirtaulPath);
```

If I change Application Pool Identity to Local System then I am able to get the information. Is there anyway If I can get IIS information(for e.g. SiteName, ApplicationPoolName, IdleTimeout, RuntimeVersion etc) without changing anything with default setting of Application Pool?

Comment: Would you want the app pool identity to have that kind of access? It's the same reason that you have to run IIS manager as admin.

Comment: By design. Not likely to see a change recently, but maybe possible with the new REST API.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I don't want to change default setting of Application pool